# Is it possible to shutdown someone else's computer from your computer in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, remote-access, shutdown

So I've been pondering on this for about a week, is it possible to use a Batch file to shut someone else's computer off? I already know that `shutdown.exe /s` or `shutdown.exe /s /t 00` shuts down your own computer, and that by replacing `/s` with `/l` or `/r` will logoff or restart your computer, but what I want to know is that is it possible to remotely shut someone else's computer off with similar commands. Obviously the code will be really complex if it is possible

Comment: `<humor>`Before or after the next Microsoft Patch Tuesday? `</humor>`  (You need appropriate credentials as Ken White answered before I finished typing)

Comment: What? I'm not quit sure I know what you're talking about.

Comment: If it were possible without credentials then it would be a huge security hole and we could confidently expect a patch to appear as soon as the issue was brought to Microsoft's attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, provided you have sufficient rights on the remote computer to do so. See the [documentation for shutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732503%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), particularly the `/m` switch.

```
shutdown /m \\computertoshutdown
```

For information about the required rights, see the Remarks page in the linked documentation.

Comment: so I will need a domain to shut it down, would using my internal ip address work or will I need to buy a static ip?

Comment: No, I didn't say that. I gave an example - replace `\\yourdomain` with the name of the computer. If you can access the computer via IP address, use the IP address. The documentation tells you what you need in order to use the command on a remote computer. What does it tell you?

Comment: okay, I read the documentation, it seemed to clear other questions I had, thanks btw